# How to properly use OnMapLoadedCallback in order to reference google map from MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to use MapFragment and not SupportMapFragment which is intended for API 11 and lower.

Problem is I'm stuck with getting map reference so I can set up some markers. I've tried everything, from extending MapFragment to using callback in various ways, reading almost all threads (And almost every thread out there is dealing with SupportMapFragment), and no matter what I get null pointer exception.

So,  I've added map fragment to my activity(this works map is added):

```
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment map =  new com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment();

activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.add(activity.findViewById(R.id.flFrame).getId(), map)
.commit();
```

How to get map reference and set marker?

Comment: Do you mean you see a NPE when calling getMap on your fragment?

Comment: Yeah, no matter what I try to get map, I always get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Google Play Services 6.5 or newer, there is now an asynchronous version of the getMap method called [`getMapAsync`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)). From the MapFragment documentation:

> A GoogleMap must be acquired using getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback). This class automatically initializes the maps system and the view.

You can do all your map-related setup in the [`onMapReady` callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback.html). The GoogleMap object returned to you in that callback will never be null:

> Once an instance of this interface is set on a MapFragment or MapView object, the onMapReady(GoogleMap) method is triggered when the map is ready to be used and provides a non-null instance of GoogleMap.